# Real time transport tracking using firebase real time database in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

How to track a transport real time like ola, uber does. In my app there are two type of users driver, user. I want to track drivers location continuously and show it to user real time on google map. I am using swift 4.2 xocode 10.1. Any doc or any guidance will a lot.

I have installed google map and pointed out the starting location and drop location and drew a polyline route using

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin this api.

Also I am able to fetch the current location of driver from the 
`func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` method.

I read some article docs about real time tracking and it is like i have to fetch the gps location of the driver continuously and send it to firebase real time database and again i have fetch the locations from user the firebase and have to move the car image along with the locations in the user end.

I did the same i send the driver location to the database and can fetch the location also but unable to proceed further please help. Thanks in advance

```
var locationRefrence: StorageReference {
    return Storage.storage().reference().child("Locations")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

    if mapViewObj == nil {
        mapViewObj = GMSMapView()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude, zoom: 16.0)
        mapViewObj = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.mapView.frame, camera: camera)
        mapViewObj.delegate = self
        mapViewObj.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapViewObj.settings.myLocationButton = true

        self.mapView.addSubview(mapViewObj)
    }

    let location = "\(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)"

    firebaseUpload(location: location)
}

func firebaseUpload(location: String) {
    let uploadLocationRef = locationRefrence.child("location")
    let locationData = location.data(using: .utf8)

    let uploadTask = uploadLocationRef.putData(locationData!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        print(metadata ?? "No metadata")
        print(error ?? "No error")
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.progress ?? "No progress")
    }

    uploadTask.resume()
}

func fetchLocationFromFirebase() {
    let downloadLocationRef = locationRefrence.child("location")

    let downloadTask = downloadLocationRef.getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 12) { (data, error) in
        if let data = data {
            let locationStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("Fetched Locations : \(locationStr ?? "Nothing fetched...")")
        }
        print(error ?? "No error")
    }

    downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.progress ?? "No progress")
    }

    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: I removed part of the title where you ask for a tutorial. That is off-topic and would of gotten your question closed as off-topic

Comment: @Scriptable Thank you, any guidance further will help me a lot.

Comment: how have you setup `location` in firebase?

Comment: I made an app in firebase and access its storage. I can see the data i submitted in firebase and can fetch it also.

Comment: ok so driver sends it... user needs to fetch it.

Comment: yes absolutely.

Comment: So what part are you having issues with, you've said the driver is sending the locations as you can see it in firebase, you cannot fetch it?

Comment: no i can fetch it my problem is how to move the car icon image along with the locations after fetching

Comment: You have shown all the code for the driver side (uploading locations) that works but not shown the user side that fetches and shows the map? show the code you need help with

Comment: fetchLocationFromFirebase is the method name by which i am fetching the driver location for showing, i already pasted it. after that i dont know how to move the marker from one location to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem I think is here:

```
let downloadTask = downloadLocationRef.getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 12) { (data, error) in
```

I have no idea why you are doing this? This isn't a good way to fetch the data firstly, but also it only fetches what is there now and does not monitor for any updates, so I think you need to do a little more research on Firebase's real time database.

For this particular case, you want to be updated any time the location is updated so you would observe the 'location' child for changes

```
refHandle = postRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
  // ...
})
```

This will give you a snapshot of the data in the locations table each time it updates

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: thank you. I will change it but how to move marker in map after getting the update?

Comment: keep a reference to the marker and update its position as needed

Comment: I was doing completely wrong... I was storing the data into storage but i have to store the data into database. Then only i can get real time changes. Thank you @Scriptable for showing me the right path.